# Can I run two external 4k monitors on 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors, displayport, thunderbolt, 4k-monitor

I was just provided with a new Dell XPS13 7390 laptop for work running 18.04.3 LTS. I need to get a dock for my peripherals and, since this thing has Thunderbolt ports, I'm considering getting a Thunderbolt dock that can (allegedly) run two external monitors at 4k, but don't want to spend the extra money if it won't work. I really have two basic questions:

Can I run two external monitors at 4k over Thunderbolt with Ubuntu 18.04.3?

Bonus: Can I run two external monitors at 4k *and* use the laptop display as well?

**Update**
We purchased the Dell WD19TB dock and, [after some good times](https://askubuntu.com/q/1195666/254743), got it working correctly with the Ubuntu 18.04 laptop. Today, I attempted to hook up two external monitors and cannot get it working. I've tried the following combinations:

*Scenario 1*
Monitor 1: DisplayPort via dock
Monitor 2: HDMI via dock
Result: Only the DisplayPort monitor works, neither the HDMI nor the native display work. When I unplug the HDMI monitor from the dock, the native display does not return to function.

*Scenario 2*
Monitor 1: DisplayPort via dock
Monitor 2: DisplayPort via dock (the dock has two standard DPs and one mini DP)
Result: Only Monitor 2 works. This one is really curious, as `xrandr` shows all three connections, if I'm reading it correctly. However, `--listmonitors` only shows 2 monitors. I can provide xrandr results if requested.

*Scenario 3*
Monitor 1: DisplayPort via dock
Monitor 2: USB-C to HDMI via an adapter from the laptop's built-in USB 3.1 Gen 2 Type-C port
Result: None of the monitors work.

I can't even find a basic tutorial on how to get two external 4k monitors to work on Ubuntu, let alone with any of the configurations I'm dealing with. Does *anyone* have any guidance?

Comment: Ports and Slots Ports & Slots at https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/cty/pdp/spd/xps-13-7390-2-in-1-laptop?#features_section says ...
_1. Thunderbolt™ 3 with power delivery and DisplayPort (4 lanes of PCI Express Gen 3) | 2. 3.5mm headphone/microphone combo jack| 3. Thunderbolt™ 3 with power delivery and DisplayPort (4 lanes of PCI Express Gen 3) | 4. microSD card reader_ so it may be possible. To be sure, ask Dell; if it won't do it with Windows, it surely won't with Ubuntu.

Comment: @K7AAY - I'm almost certain that it will on Windows as I could run two 4k's from different ports on my old laptop. I was just wondering if 18.04 supported it _at all_, or is that something that _could possibly_ be supported given the correct drivers/packages?

Comment: Short answer: yes. Long answer: YES and YES. First you have to buy the right Thunderbolt 3 device that supports Linux. Beware of the ones that only support 4K at 30Hz refresh rate. They are harder on your eyes.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - This is *exactly* the kind of information I'm looking for. Would you be willing to add an answer with this information and, if you're willing, an example of a Thunderbolt 3 dock that supports Linux?

Comment: @AJ. I've only heard horror stories about docks not the good stories. My laptop has internal 1920x1080, TB3 to HDMI converter 4K@54 HZ, nVidia GTX 970M HDMI at 1920x1080. Three monitors work great.

Comment: Did you manage to use 1 external monitor at 4k with the builtin laptop display?

Comment: @Peter Yes, I can use the built-in display and an external monitor, both at 4k. Problem is, it's an XPS13. While I love the portability, I'd love to be able to hook it up to something big when I'm at my desk.

Comment: @AJ. Thanks. Just for the record, I had no problem with a 4k Dell monitor either. Using the "Dell Adapter USB-C to HDMI/DP with Power Pass-Through".